# Using sql functions that require options with @Formula annotation in Java Spring

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I am trying to use the SQL's DATEDIFF method in a Java Entity, and Java is interpreting the DAY option of DATEDIFF as a property inside of the model and not an option of said function

I have found a lot of articles on using the @Formula annotation in Spring, but I am yet to find one that takes an SQL variable as a parameter.

```
private String fecInaguracion;
private String fecFirmaContrato;
@Formula(value="DATEDIFF(DAY, fecFirmaContrato, getdate())")
private Integer diasTranscurridos;
```

Using DAY as above, Spring interprets 'DAY' as a property inside of the model. Knowing this I tried providing the option as a property inside of the model and passing that as a parameter.
Also no luck.

```
private String fecInaguracion;
private String fecFirmaContrato;
private String option = "DAY"; 
@Formula(value="DATEDIFF(option, fecFirmaContrato, getdate())")
private Integer diasTranscurridos;
```

Last attempt was trying to concatenate the option inside of the sting, also resulting in an error.

```
private String fecInaguracion;
private String fecFirmaContrato;
@Formula(value="DATEDIFF("+DAY+", fecFirmaContrato, getdate())")
private Integer diasTranscurridos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting I found a way of getting this to work, in SQL I noticed that you can wrap the option in double quotes and the option works the same.
Knowing this I started experimenting again and found that escaping the double quote characters in the model worked, and now everything is fine.

```
private String fecInaguracion;
private String fecFirmaContrato;
@Formula(value="DATEDIFF(\"DAY\", fecFirmaContrato, getdate())")
private Integer diasTranscurridos;
```

Hope this helps somebody some day!